# Are the credentials issued by GetCredentialsForIdentityCommand tied with the roles defined in Identity Pool or User Pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, authorization, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am using AWS Cognito for user AuthN and AuthZ.

**roleA** is attached to identity pool with the condition amr=authenticated (authenticated users).
roleA includes also the permission policy of s3:ListAllMyBuckets.

**roleA - Trust relationship:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "eu-central-1:XXXX" --> identityPoolId
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:groups": "Admin"
                },
                "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**roleA - Permission policy:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

**roleB** is attached to a group "Admin" in user pool.
roleB does not include this permission of s3:ListAllMyBuckets.

**roleB - Trust relationship:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "eu-central-1:XXXX" --> identityPoolId
                },
                "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

userX in group "Admin" is authenticated with user pool, then exchange the jwtIdToken with the credentials using *GetCredentialsForIdentityCommand*.
The credentials issued by Identity Pool does NOT allow the userX to list buckets in S3.

I make a change and attach the permission policy of s3:ListAllMyBuckets to roleB and remove this permission from roleA.
The same userX in group "Admin" is authenticated with user pool, then exchange the jwtIdToken with the credentials using *GetCredentialsForIdentityCommand*.
The credentials issued by Identity Pool allow the userX to list buckets in S3.

Could you help me to understand this behavior and does Cognito assign the credentials to the role?

It seems that the credentials issued by Identity Pool are tied only to roleB, how do I control that?

Does *GetCredentialsForIdentityCommand* return credentials for the role that is attached to the identity pool or to the group (Admin) in the user pool?

Here is the code to exchange the jwtIdToken with the credentials:

```
const identityId = (
  await client.send(
    new GetIdCommand({
      IdentityPoolId: identityPoolId,
      Logins: {
        [cognitoIdentityPool]: jwtIdToken,
      },
    })
  )
).IdentityId;

console.log('identityId', identityId);

const credentials = (
  await client.send(
    new GetCredentialsForIdentityCommand({
      IdentityId: identityId,
      Logins: {
        [cognitoIdentityPool]: jwtIdToken,
      },
    })
  )
).Credentials;
```

Comment: I've done some research and come out to these conclusions:

Comment: what is this `cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:groups` condition context key? this is a thing? i could not find it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The authenticated and unauthenticated roles are the default roles values that will be assumed by users based on their authentication status unless overridden by roleMappings.
It is referred to 'Use default authenticated role' in the AWS Console.
Without roleMappings, Cognito is default to using the roles specified in the roles field based on the user's authentication status.

roleMappings is an optional field.
When it exists, Cognito Identity prioritizes the settings here over what is defined by roles field.
In the code above, it is referred to 'Choose role with preferred_role claim in tokens' in the AWS Console.

The ambiguousRoleResolution setting determines what role to assume if the roleMappings result is in an ambiguous situation where multiple roles could be assumed.
Setting it to 'AuthenticatedRole' means that in such cases, the role specified under authenticated in the roles field will be used.